# Fixed content in bootstrap with no responsiveness

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Strange question I know, as this goes against the whole purpose of bootstrap and its responsiveness however its something I have to do.....

I would like a 3 column layout, the left and right columns can just be col-xs-1 for example and the centre column col-xs-10 so its the main content area, but we have the columns either side we can possibly use going forward.

Obviously this is easy to create, however, we've been asked to make the centre column non responsive........

So long story short, I need my centre column, and all the elements within it, like the nav, action bar, plus content etc, to be completely static and refrain from re-sizing.

Any idea's? I've tried lots of suggestions with setting a fixed with for the column etc but nothing seems to work.

Cheers

```
      <div class="container">
```

```
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <!-- The mobile navbar-toggle button can be safely removed since you do not need it in a non-responsive implementation -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <xp:image url="/NewLogoWhiteText.gif"
                        id="image1">
                    </xp:image>
                </a>
    </div>


    <!-- Note that the .navbar-collapse and .collapse classes have been removed from the #navbar -->
    <div id="navbar">
      <p class="navbar-text">
                    <strong>
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2"
                            value="#{javascript:return database.getTitle()}">
                        </xp:text>
                    </strong>
                </p>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li>

                    <p class="navbar-text navbar-left">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"
                            aria-hidden="true">
                        </span>
                        <xp:text escape="true"
                            id="computedField1">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:" " + @Name("[CN]", @UserName());}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                    </p>

                </li>   
                    <li>
                        <xp:button value="Personal" id="button2"
                            styleClass="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-xs">
                        </xp:button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <xp:button value="Admin" id="button1"
                            styleClass="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-xs">
                        </xp:button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <xp:button value="System" id="button3"
                            styleClass="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-xs">
                        </xp:button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <xp:button value="Help?" id="button4"
                            styleClass="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-xs">
                        </xp:button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
  </div>

</nav>

  </div>
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried for the fixed column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the [Disable resposive](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive) section in the Bootstrap documentation? And if so, where is it going wrong for you, maybe add a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example?

### Steps to disable page responsiveness

> 1. Omit the viewport  mentioned in the CSS docs
> 2. Override the width on the .container for each grid tier with a single width, for example width: 970px !important; Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the !important with media queries or some selector-fu.
> 3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
> 4. For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.
>
> You'll still need Respond.js for IE8 (since our media queries are still there and need to be processed). This disables the "mobile site" aspects of Bootstrap.

[View the non-responsive example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/)

Comment: Hi Neejoh,

Thanks, I'm now very close to what I need. The only thing bugging me is my navbar drops down to 2 lines when I reach 767px - Should this be happening if I've disabled responsiveness?

I've edited my question to show my code